# WCF single endpoint with multiple service contracts discovery

Tags: c#, wcf, service-discovery

I use single endpoint with multiple service contracts. For example:

In interface assembly:

```
public interface IServer1 { ... }

public interface IServer2 { ... }
```

In server assembly:

```
internal interface IServer : IServer1, IServer2 {}

internal class Server : IServer
{
    ...
    var host = new ServiceHost(this);
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServer), ...);
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    ...
}
```

In client assemblies:

```
internal class Client1
{
    ...
    var factory = new ChannelFactory<IServer1>(...);
    ...
}

internal class Client2
{
    ...
    var factory = new ChannelFactory<IServer2>(...);
    ...
}
```

It works just fine, except service discovery case:

```
var discovery = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
discovery.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IServer1)); // Not found
discovery.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IServer2)); // Not found
```

Is there any way to discover IServer1 and IServer2 without exposing IServer?